Find a basis for $V$ in which the Gram matrix of $\beta$ has a diagonal form.
Let $V = \mathbb{R}[x]_{\leqslant 2}$ be the space of polynomials of degree at most 2.
(a) Determine the Gram matrix for the bilinear forms
$$
\beta: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad \beta(f, g) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x + y) f(x) g(y) dx \, dy
$$
in the basis $1, x, x^2$.
(b) Find a basis for $V$ in which the Gram matrix of $\beta$ has a diagonal form.

What I have so far:
If I didnt make a mistake the Gram matrix calculated in a) should be:
$$
G = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{7}{12} & \frac{5}{12} \\
\frac{7}{12} & \frac{5}{12} & \frac{13}{40} \\
\frac{5}{12} & \frac{13}{40} &  \frac{4}{15}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so now there remains b) wich is my main question. I dont know how to calculate the basis Vectors of $V$.
I already calculated a Matrix $S$ so that $S^T G S = D$ (with $D$ being a Diagonal matix). By using a method wich executes row and column tranformations at the same time:
$$
S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\frac{7}{12} & \frac{23}{110} \\
0 & 1 & -\frac{59}{55} \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
S^T G S = \frac{1}{39600}\begin{pmatrix}
39600 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3025 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 204
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but I have problems on continuing from here. I calculated above "Diagonalized" form because I found the following formula in my lecture notes and thought this could be useful in some way, but Im kinda stuck on how to use it now (if its even usefull):
$$
G_C(\beta)=\left(T_{\mathcal{B}}^C\right)^t \cdot G_{\mathcal{B}}(\beta) \cdot T_{\mathcal{B}}^C
$$

What book are you using?  So far as I can tell you are actually working on the vector space $V$ of real polynomial functions of degree at most $2$ not polynomials themselves.  It's an important distinction in algebra but not so much in analysis.   Anyway with $g_{i,j} = \beta(x^{i-1}, x^{j-1})$ then for the matrix $G':=(G S)$  by applying matrix multiplication and bilinearity you should have $g_{i,j}' = \beta(x^{i-1},\sum_{k=1}^3 s_{k,j}\cdot x^{k-1})$  and you can then compute $S^T G' =S^TGS$ similarly (though you can actually skip ahead due to symmetry).
